# sshfs - device not found

Tags: linux, mount, sshfs, fuse

After updating the server with `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` this command return an error

## command

```
echo "the-password" | sshfs root@domain.com:/var/www /remote_mount -o password_stdin
```

## OS

```
Debian 3.2.60-1+deb7u3 x86_64 (wheezy)
```

## error

```
fuse: device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first
```

## modprobe fuse

```
root@dyntest-amd-3700-2gb ~ # modprobe fuse
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'fuse': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)

root@dyntest-amd-3700-2gb ~ # dmesg | grep fuse
[   20.126156] fuse: Unknown symbol nosteal_pipe_buf_ops (err 0)
[1607702.343086] fuse: Unknown symbol nosteal_pipe_buf_ops (err 0)
[1607745.824310] fuse: Unknown symbol nosteal_pipe_buf_ops (err 0)
[1607908.188559] fuse: Unknown symbol nosteal_pipe_buf_ops (err 0)
[1608724.690945] fuse: Unknown symbol nosteal_pipe_buf_ops (err 0)
[1608741.684927] fuse: Unknown symbol nosteal_pipe_buf_ops (err 0)
[2565283.964259] fuse: Unknown symbol nosteal_pipe_buf_ops (err 0)
```

## Kernel version

```
root@dyntest-amd-3700-2gb ~ # cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.2.0-4-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Debian 4.6.3-14) ) #1 SMP Debian 3.2.54-2

root@dyntest-amd-3700-2gb ~ # locate -i -r /fuse
/bin/fuser
/bin/fusermount
/etc/fuse.conf
/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/fs/fuse
/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/fs/fuse/cuse.ko
/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/fs/fuse/fuse.ko
/lib/modules-load.d/fuse.conf
/usr/include/boost/fusion/functional/adapter/fused.hpp
/usr/include/boost/fusion/functional/adapter/fused_function_object.hpp
/usr/include/boost/fusion/functional/adapter/fused_procedure.hpp
/usr/include/boost/fusion/include/fused.hpp
/usr/include/boost/fusion/include/fused_function_object.hpp
/usr/include/boost/fusion/include/fused_procedure.hpp
/usr/include/linux/fuse.h
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/fusermount
/usr/share/doc/fuse
/usr/share/doc/fuse/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/fuse/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/fuse/copyright
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fuse
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/fuse
/usr/share/man/man1/fuser.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/fusermount.1.gz
/var/cache/apt/archives/fuse_2.9.0-2+deb7u1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/fuse_2.9.3-14_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/fuse_2.9.3-15_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/fuse_2.9.3-9_amd64.deb
/var/lib/dpkg/info/fuse.conffiles
/var/lib/dpkg/info/fuse.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/fuse.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/fuse.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/fuse.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/fuse.preinst
```

## update

```
root@dyntest-amd-3700-2gb ~ # apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-generic linux-image
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package linux-image is a virtual package provided by:
  linux-image-3.2.0-4-rt-amd64 3.2.60-1+deb7u3
  linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64 3.2.60-1+deb7u3
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Unable to locate package linux-image-generic
E: Package 'linux-image' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post solves the problem..

Just need to update the kernel

http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=113906

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you also upgraded your kernel, right? Check the `apt-get` logs. If yes:

```
reboot
```

simple as that. You upgraded your kernel and now you're trying to load a kernel module which is too new for your kernel.

Not that you asked, but: Beware that an `echo <password> | ..` will be normally saved to your password into `~/.bash_history`. This is especially dangerous as you seem to use `root` login on an publicly accessible server.

Comment: have rebooted.. same error

Comment: @clarkk To bad. Check you *apt* log nonetheless. The error indicates, that the kernels module is incompatible with the kernel itself. You could also try to reinstall the kernel.

Comment: How to reinstall the kernel (I'm not an expert)

Comment: You didn't specify your OS (debian/ubuntu?) and system (regular PC/virtual machine/virtual host/raspi..). If ubuntu, try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-generic linux-image`. If it doesn't help, we need more info on the error. You can also try to `sudo dpkg-reconfigure fuse`.

Comment: Debian 3.2.60-1+deb7u3 x86_64 (wheezy).. Have updated the question with output from the syntax you wrote